# Find lists with most overlapping items

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have a list of dicts that looks like this:

```
[{'black olives',
  'feta cheese crumbles',
  'garbanzo beans',
  'garlic',
  'grape tomatoes',
  'pepper',
  'purple onion',
  'romaine lettuce',
  'seasoning'},
 {'eggs',
  'green tomatoes',
  'ground black pepper',
  'ground pepper',
  'milk',
  'plain flour',
  'salt',
  'thyme',
  'tomatoes',
  'vegetable oil',
  'yellow corn meal'},
 {'butter',
  'chicken livers',
  'cooking oil',
  'eggs',
  'garlic powder',
  'green chilies',
  'grilled chicken breasts',
  'mayonaise',
  'pepper',
  'salt',
  'soy sauce',
  'yellow onion'},
 {'salt', 'vegetable oil', 'water', 'wheat'},
 {'bay leaf',
  'black pepper',
  'boneless chicken skinless thigh',
  'butter',
  'cayenne pepper',
  'chili powder',
  'cornflour',
  'double cream',
  'garam masala',
  'garlic paste',
  'ground cumin',
  'lemon juice',
  'milk',
  'natural yogurt',
  'oil',
  'onions',
  'passata',
  'salt',
  'shallots',
  'water'}]
```

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a given list index (a) as input and returns the indices of the lists (b) with the highest value of `len(a & b)`.

At the most basic level I would assume this function would look like

```
for l in lists:
    sim = len(a&b)
return l.index if sim == sim.max()
```

But I can't quite get there. I know I need to loop through all the lists that aren't a, compute an overlap, and then return the index of the list with the highest overlap.

Comment: Are you trying to get the set with most items from the list?

Comment: You need to understand your problem and your tools.  You input is a list of sets, not dicts.  Your proposed code tries to use bit-wise and (`&`), rather than set intersection.  You have the right algorithm; just apply the appropriate operations, and you should have useful code to show us.

Answer (score 0):

With a nested for-loop, you can count the amount of overlaps that each set has with other sets and keep track of the current index with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and ignore itself using an [identity comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) (`is`):

```
def highest_overlap(list_of_sets):
    highest = None

    for i, candidate in enumerate(list_of_sets):
        overlaps = 0

        for other in list_of_sets:
            if other is candidate:
                # Same set; skip
                continue

            overlaps += len(candidate & other)

        if highest is None or highest[1] < overlaps:
            highest = (i, overlaps)

    return highest

>>> print(highest_overlap(ingredients))
(1, 6)
```